# Problem with DL-524 router

Tags: router

I have a proble with a DL-524 router.

The router is a bit far away from my laptop, so i bought 20m of screened utp cable.

the cable is ok, i've tested it, but when i plug it in the modem and the router i get no internet connectivity with the wan led blinking.

Can someone help?

thank's
Sebastian

Comment: If "screened" mean shielded, then it's STP not UTP.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is a DLINK router, and your using cable internet connection?
Can you ping the router?
you may find you need to power down the modem if it is cable at the mains then power back on whilst the nic is connected to the router.

It is also worth making sure there is no USB connection to the modem.